# Any way to surround selection with braces automatically on typing {, using VS2012 and ReSharper 8?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can make a selection and use the ReSharper action-menu to surround with braces, or use one of the many "Surround with..." keyboard shortcuts.

What I am looking for is a way to do the following (aka the laziest possible way):

1. Select some code
2. Press {
3. The selected text is now surrounded with braces.

This works in e.g. Xamarin Studio (for [,{,( braces).

Is there any way to achieve this in Visual Studio, either using built-in functionality or a plugin?

Comment: Visual Assist X does this as well. I'm switching from native to more and more managed code where R# is plain better and disabled VAX for a variety of reasons so a replacement for that would be really rad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write a resharper plugin to do it. You can register a typing assist handler for a particular character (such as '{') by calling `ITypingAssistManager.AddTypingHandler`. Your handler should look to see if the document has a selection, and modify the document to insert the open and closing character around the selection contents.

The only problem might be precedence - the '{' character will already have a handler for C# documents. Adding another handler will add it to the end of the chain of handlers, and the existing handler might jump in first. In which case, you could register yourself with `ITextControlManager.AddTypingHandler`, which is what `TypingAssistManager` does, but it allows specifying a priority, so you can be called before `TypingAssistManager`.

As ever, point dotPeek at the ReSharper bin folder and start spelunking for usages of `AddTypingHandler`, or look at the implementation of `TypingAssistManager`.